# I got stuck with this image background situation and bottom side bar

Tags: html, css, background

I am new to Web Development, I got stuck with this image background as it is not using it's width a 100% and on the right hand side it is showing a blank white space and I don't know what it is and moreover is showing a bottom side bar.

I am using sublime text.

If anyone can explain what wrong with this code that'll be helpful. I don't know how to explain it better.

```css
.container{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a:hover{
    color:yellow;
}

#prof{
    color:white;
    font-size: 1.2;
}

#bottom h3{
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 1.2;
    background-color: coral;

}
.button-1:hover{
    color:yellow;
}

.button-1
{
    background-color:white;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 1.2;
    width:20%;
    border:none;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

body{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body a{
    text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}

/*HEADER*/

header{
    background-color:   #000000;
    border-bottom: 3px red solid; 
}
header h1{
    float: left;
}
header nav{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
header a{
    padding:0px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*MIDDLE SECTION*/
 #middle{
    width:100%;
   padding:60px;
   margin:0px;
   color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80') no-repeat 0;   
overflow: hidden;
}

#title-1{
    background-color: black;
    padding:-10px 0px;
    color:white;
}

 .container h3{
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .container .button-1{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top:30px;
    
}



.float{ 
    width:30%;
display: inline;
float: right;

padding: 30px 2px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
text-align: center;
}
.float img{
    width: 30%


}

@media(max-width:768px){
header #prof, header nav, section .float{
    float: none;
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.container .button-1, .container h3{
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

}
.container .button-1{
    padding-top: 10px 0px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WinterMist</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Random\OneDrive\Desktop\My work\sitestyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="prof"><span style="color:red">Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
        
        <nav>
            <a href="#" style="color: red">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<section >
    
        <div id="middle">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 style="font-size: 40px"><span style="color:black">Affordable</span> Professional <span style="color:red">Websites</span></h1>
            <p style="font-size: 15px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="title-1">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Subscribe To Our Newsletter</h3>
        <button class="button-1">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="float">
            <img src="C:\Users\Random\OneDrive\Desktop\My work\img\html.jpg">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="float">
            <img src="C:\Users\Random\OneDrive\Desktop\My work\img\css.png">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="float">
            <img src="C:\Users\Random\OneDrive\Desktop\My work\img\js.png">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
<footer id="bottom">
    <h3>Copyright &#169; 2020 </h3>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: `footer` must be **inside** the `body`.

Comment: for the background issue: please check out css reference first for background-size options: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp
i think 'cover' would be useful for your case, although the image is just not appropriate for this height - you'd need to increase the height of the div as well

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS for background image and it will also remove horizontal scroll from the page

```
#middle {
width: 100%;
padding: 60px;
margin: 0px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80') no-repeat 0;
background-size: auto;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: cover;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks the reply bro,it helped. <3

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover;` in **#middle** Hope it works

```
#middle {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 60px;
   margin: 0px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80) no-repeat 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your .css file , in the middle segment where you write *#middle styles*, you made some mistakes.

***Solution:**

1. **add background-size in cover mode** which means **any image is to be set at background containing the whole portion of your container (even if for short length image,it will be streached)**. For better view you **may add fixed center in background**.
2. **padding and margin is not necessary** for this segment about this particular problem (applicable for chrome, mozilla firefox and MS Edge)
3. you **may add height equals 100%** for better view in all compatible browser
4. In your webpage **there is some margins in the whole body (occurs both in MS Edge and Chrome) , so I think if it is by mistake then you can add margin:0px in your body code inside .css file.**

***Full Code which I Updated:**

```
#middle{width:100%;height:100%;color:white;text-align:center;background:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80') no-repeat fixed center;background-size:cover;overflow-x:hidden;}
```